# Monitoring File Changes in C#

Tags: c#, file, project

I'm using C# for a mini project of mine, I am trying to monitor files that are changed, Deleted, And/or created. And export that to a file. But I am not quite sure how to monitor files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to monitor file creation, modifications, deletions and renames.

You have the following events available:

- [`Changed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx)
- [`Created`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx)
- [`Deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted.aspx)
- [`Renamed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

you can only monitor one Directory with FSW, if you want more you may have to make multiple instances of FSW. It monitors the directory not the file; if the file is moved (`changed`+`created`; `changed`+`renamed`) then you need another FSW for that destination folder.

Comment: According to the following article, you can tell the FileSystemWatcher to monitor subdirectories by setting the FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories property to true.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yep, [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) will do this.  Be careful what you wish for, because this thing watches everything!

Have a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ashben/archive/2003/10/14/31773.aspx), it explains how you it can fire multiple events (eg when a file is moved, firing an OnChange and OnCreate